# Can I display a list of categories in a post?

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

Using the List Category Posts plugin by Fernando Briano is it possible to display a list of all the posts in a particular category and have the titles of posts as links to the posts?

I am using that plugin to do this in the side bar as a widget but was hoping I could also do it on a post or page.

Or if there is another plugin that can do that that would be good.

Thanks.

Comment: have you read the part about using shortcode in the plugin 'description' and 'other notes' of that plugin? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/

Answer (score 1):

As Michael mentions in the comments, you can use the shortcode in a post or page to do the same the widget does:

```
[catlist argument1=value1 argument2=value2]
```

Please, people, read the README file on plugins. We developers take the time to write it so you can use our plugins.

- First rule of installing a new WordPress Plugin is read the
  documentation.
- Second rule of installing a new WordPress Plugin is
  **read the documentation**.